# Execute Folium Library code in RMarkdown chunk doesn´t show up map

Tags: python, r-markdown, rstudio, folium

I`m working with RMarkdown and Python, I just created a chunk where I add code relate to the folium library, but I can create the report or show up the map

Chunk setup in my RMarkdown Report, I`m al so working with matplotlib in the same RMarkdown report a nd it works fine

````
```{r setup,include=FALSE}
library(reticulate)

library(ggplot2)

library(lattice)

library(vembedr)

use_python("C:/Users/renzocrossi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe")

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo=TRUE,message = FALSE,warning = FALSE)
````

This is the code in the RMarkdown chunk about folium

````
```{python}
import folium

m = folium.Map(location = [46.20, 6.144], zoom_start=6, tiles="OpenStreetMap")

fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="My Map")
fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[40.12, 10.1], popup="Hi I'am a Marker", 
icon=folium.Icon(color='green')))
m.add_child(fg)
m
```
<folium.folium.Map object at 0x000001F6A1098B20>
````

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code in Python and didn't get an output either. The only way that I think this would work as-is is in a Jupyter notebook. (I think!)

However, with just a bit more, you can definitely get the map on the document. I added `import webbrowswer` so that I could export the map as HTML, then render it in R Markdown.

````
```{python mapper, include=FALSE}
import folium
import webbrowser

m = folium.Map(location = [46.20, 6.144], zoom_start=6, tiles="OpenStreetMap")

fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="My Map")
fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[40.12, 10.1], popup="Hi I'am a Marker", 
icon = folium.Icon(color='green')))
m.add_child(fg)

m.save("map.html")

webbrowser.open("map.html")
```
````

Then outside of the Python chunk (not in any chunk), I called the map.

```
![](map.html)

![](map.html){width=100% height=800px}
```

I don't know if you have any default figure sizes set, I didn't for this example. However, the calls of this map rendered this:

[image]

By the way, the maps are still completely interactive, as they would be in Python or if rendered directly through R.

For example, I decreased magnification and rendered the following:

[image]